# ZookeeperConnectionException in HBase Standalone mode

Tags: hbase

I'm using hbase-0.90.0. I'm running it in standalone mode. While trying to execute any commands from "hbase shell" it is giving me the following error.

hbase(main):003:0> status 'detailed'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase

I'm new to HBase. Can you please help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For one reason or another your HBase Client is not talking to Zookeeper. I just had the same problem and the issue for me was that the hbase config (hbase-site.xml) had the wrong port for the zookeeper (The default is 2181 and someone had set it to 2182 incorrectly). The config for using zookeeper is at http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#zookeeper.

Also checking what hbase and zookeeper think their names are and what they actually are. A usual suspect is that the /etc/hosts file has some extra entries for localhost / 127.0.0.1. So make sure your localhost has only one line for localhost and put all the aliases for 127.0.0.1 on a single line in /etc/hosts

Sometimes having the ipv4 and ipv6 entries in localhost confuses things, so try commenting out all the ipv6 entries (the ones with colons ':' in the address.)

Answer (score 2):

so i had the exact same problem and changing the /etc/hosts file did it for me. I changed it so that 'localhost' and my host name both pointed to '127.0.0.1'

see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/19718 for more details.

Comment: Woo hoo! This fixed the same problem for me. Well, my problem was almost the same: I was running Hbase Version 0.90.4, and the exact error message I got was "ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: HBase is able to connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately. This could be a sign that the server has too many connections (30 is the default)."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I first started up HBase standalone mode on my mac 10.9. I fixed several parameters, but not sure which one really works. Anyway, below is the place that I make changes:

1. `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

   make sure only one localhost, and it is 127.0.0.1
2. Edit hbase-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>
     <property>
         <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
         <value>file:///usr/local/hbase</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
         <value>usr/local/zookeeper</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
         <value>2181</value>
     </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. Edit `hbase-env.sh`

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
   (Warning: this path is the Java 1.6 path, seems that Java 1.7 does not support HBase)

   export HBASE_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
   (fix realm issue)
   ```

And now you shall be good! *Good Luck!*

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. To solve it i followed below steps.

1. Edit ***hbase-env.sh***

```html
@rem The java implementation to use.  Java 1.6 required.
@rem set JAVA_HOME=c:\apps\java
```

2. Edit ***hbase-site.xml***

   ```
   <configuration>
      <property>
         <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
         <!-- <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value> -->
         <!-- <value>hdfs://192.168.203.130:9000/hbase</value> -->
         <value>/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.98.5/hbase</value> 
         <description> The directory shared by RegionServers. </description>
      </property>

      <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
         <!--<value>/tmp/zookeeper</value>-->
         <value>/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.98.5/zookeeper</value>
         <!-- <value>/usr/local/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/export</value> -->
         <description>
               Property from ZooKeeper config zoo.cfg.
               The directory where the snapshot is stored.
         </description>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
         <value>2181</value>
     </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. open ***.bashrc*** set Hbase PATH Environmental variable

```html
#HBASE HOME <br>
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.98.5

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HBASE_HOME/bin
```

4. Execute ***.bashrc*** file

```html
    hduser@ubuntu:~$source ~/.bashrc
```

5. Execute ***start-hbase.sh*** command in your terminal

```html
                   hduser@ubuntu:~$ start-hbase.sh
    hduser@ubuntu:~$ hbase shell
    hduser@ubuntu:~$ list
```

Thanks